# RPM encrypt/decrypt with YUM / Zypper

Tags: encryption, gnupg, yum, rpm, zypper

I´d like to create a repository with encrypted RPM Packages.

The Host get´s the GPG Key for decryption.
If there a way to "auto decrypt" the packes with yum / zypper ?

Answer (score 0):

Nope. The gpg key used by Yum (and likely by Zypper) is used only to *verify the signature*. I.e. there is signature of the payload in the header so you can verify that the content has not been altered. But it is not used for encryption or decryption.